# How to disconnect anonymous MutationObserver from document element without replacing element with its clone?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

While making a tampermonkey script that should change attribute on multiple document elements, I encountered a site that uses event listener to prevent any changes to that attribute. To counter such behavior I can replace elements with their clones, like below:

```
const map = new Map();

function read() {
    for (let image of [...document.getElementsByTagName('img')]) {
        const clone = image.cloneNode(/* with children */true);
        // TODO: modify the clone
        map.set(image, clone);
    }
}

read();

function write() {
    for (let [image, clone] of map) {
        image.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, image);
    }
}

write();

map.clear();
```

But with this method there is a problem: browser (Chrome 71) in the end of operation will recalculate style and sometimes thrash layout if the quantity of elements is large (10 elements - no thrashing, 100 elements - trashing). I tried to modify loop in write function with requesting animation frame:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(document.replaceChild.bind(image.parentNode, clone, image));
```

But it still thrashes layout.
Tried to insert a pause in the loop:

```
async function write() {
  for (let [image, clone] of map) {
    await new Promise(window.requestAnimationFrame);
    image.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, image);
  }
}
```

No change. Tried to split elements array in small chunks and operate each chunk, but browser still recalculates style lazily in the end and thrashes layout.
So instead of replacing each element with its clone I can remove each event listener with something like:

```
for (let image of [...document.getElementsByTagName('img')]) {
  const listeners = getEventListeners(image);
  for (let event_type in listeners) {
    for (let event of listeners[event_type]) {
      image.removeEventListener(event.type, event.listener, event.useCapture);
    }
  }
}
```

While this fixes the problem, there is still the question: what if a site used not event listener, but MutationObserver to prevent modification of the document elements? Is there a way to remove MutationObserver without replacing document element with its clone?

Though I understand that modifying the attributes of lots of elements will still force browser to reflow, my question still stands.

Comment: There's no such method. Also note, the site can just as well detect the element being deleted from DOM using IntersectionObserver or a dumb interval check and reattach to the new element.

Comment: To be more specific, what website are you talking about? And what are you trying to do finally?

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks. Will note.

Comment: @KoshVery, the site in question is [this forum](https://4pda.ru/forum/). Tampermonkey script is modifying href of link/anchor tags so I can skip link handlers(like steam link-filter) and go right into desirable site. [Raw](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/HK49/b5594ba59a96699442f998abc6d00e42/raw/afeeb72c2263493f9549c84b5cf4703924de26d3/Simple%2520url-cleaner%2520from%2520tracking.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disconnect anonymous MutationObserver, but it does not mean there is no another solution.

I believe that you do not need to change **all** the links on the page.
You need to intercept just **one** link which the user would try to follow.

Please see the snippet below.

We want to change `href` attribute and it's being catched by the observer:

```js
// anonymous observer:
(new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (
      mutation.type == 'attributes' &&
      mutation.target.href !== 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
    ) {
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
      mutation.target.href = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
    }
  }
}))
.observe(
  document.querySelector('html'), {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true
  }
);

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a) {
  a.href = 'https://yastatic.net/www/_/x/Q/xk8YidkhGjIGOrFm_dL5781YA.svg';
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png">Google</a>
```

To avoid this, set event listeners to the links and on `click` change `location.href` (or open a new tab or window) instead of changing `a.href`:

```js
// anonymous observer:
(new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (
      mutation.type == 'attributes' &&
      mutation.target.href !== 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
    ) {
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
      mutation.target.href = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'
    }
  }
}))
.observe(
  document.querySelector('html'), {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true
  }
);

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = 'https://yastatic.net/www/_/x/Q/xk8YidkhGjIGOrFm_dL5781YA.svg';
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png">Google</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed solution to bypass the observer on link href attribute without cloning the link tag. But there are two details that make me uncomfortable: on infinite scroll pages with each new link there would be new listener (won't my computer explode?) and user can't preview the url on hover (ain't this bad?). Also while your answer is useful, I don't know if I should mark my question answered, 'cause as far as I understand there is no way to disconnect anonymous MutationObserver on document element?

Comment: @That'sme-whoelse, thank you for your note! I've updated my answer to answer your question explicitly -- you cannot disconnect it if it's anonymous. Regarding infinite scroll, if you comfortable with loading infinite content, don't worry of event listeners either =)) Seriously, you might set one delegated `touchstart/mousedown` listener then in its callback set `click` listener -- you'll probably save some memory. The second, user can't preview url on hover -- this is solvable too but out of this question scope.